# JavaScript - Resultado inesperado con eventos y getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

[Por favor, solo soluciones aplicando únicamente JS Vanilla]

Tengo un resultado inesperado añadiendo eventos a un array obtenido con el getElementsByClassName.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    numeros[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var elemento = numeros[i];

        if (esCero()) {
            resultadoHTML.innerHTML = elemento.innerHTML;
        } else {
            console.log(elemento);
            resultadoHTML.innerHTML += elemento.innerHTML;
        }
    });
}
```

En la calculadora que estoy haciendo, hay varios elementos HTML que comparten la clase ".numeros", para 10 divs (números del 0-9). Cuando se clicka en un número, siempre hace la iteración como que es el número 5, aunque clique en otro número cualquiera.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes resolver utilizando [**setAttribute() Method**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp). El resultado sería agregar `onclick="myEvent(this)"` a cada botón. De este modo vas poder registrar los eventos sin problemas y realizar las acciones pertinentes dentro de tu función `myEvent()`

**Código de ejemplo:**

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myClassName");

for(i=0; i< btns.length;i++)
{
   btns[i].setAttribute("onclick", "myEvent(this)");
}

function myEvent(obj){
  console.log("click button", obj.textContent)
}
```

```html
<button class="myClassName">1</button>
<button class="myClassName">2</button>
<button class="myClassName">3</button>
<button class="myClassName">4</button>
<button class="myClassName">5</button>
<button class="myClassName">6</button>
<button class="myClassName">7</button>
<button class="myClassName">8</button>
<button class="myClassName">9</button>
<button class="myClassName">0</button>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo capturando el event del click asi:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    numeros[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var elemento = e.target;
    if (esCero()) {
resultadoHTML.innerHTML = elemento.innerHTML;
} else { 
console.log(elemento); resultadoHTML.innerHTML += elemento.innerHTML;
 } 
});
}
```